# Using date in the Django url templatetag

Tags: django, django-templates, django-urls

I am trying to build a date-based URL with Django's url template tag. I have a datetime object that I can display like so:

```
{{block|date:"F j Y"}}
```

However, when I use nearly the same syntax with the url templatetag, like so:

```
{% url meeting block|date:"Y" %}
```

I get an error -- it appears that the only thing passed to url is an empty string:

```
... Reverse for 'meeting' with arguments '(u'',)' and arguments ...
```

What might I be doing wrong?

Comment: Does putting {{ block|date:"Y" }} before your url tag call produce the expected value?  Also... if block is a datetime object, cant you just use block.year?

Comment: Oddly, block.year etc. doesn't seem to work -- I still get an empty string (non-unicode this time, hrm). But thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: That is, it works outside the {% url %} tag but not inside.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `url` tag is a bit strange, and is very picky about its arguments. In particular, I don't think it evaluates any filters in its arguments.

You could try this:

```
{% with block|date:"Y" as blockyear %}{% url meeting blockyear %}{% endwith %}
```